# Find all values with in a range and then offset

Tags: excel, vba, loops, offset

I am trying to write vba code which looks for the term "drek" in column BI. If the term is present in the cell it will then offset (0,1) the value "1".

I have used the code below, however it will only find and offset the first "drek" and then stop. I need it so it will do this with every "drek" it finds.

How might I do this?

```
Sub find_drek()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim sFind As String

    sFind = "drek"
    Set rng = Range("BI2", Range("BI65536").End(xlUp))
    Set cl = rng.find(sFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1"
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to put `for each cell in rng` after `Set rng` line, change the `Set cl and if not` line to `if cell.value=sFind then cell.offset(0,1).value="1" ` then put `Next` before End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim sFind As String

sFind = "drek"

For Each rng In Range("BI2", Range("BI65536").End(xlUp))
    If Not rng.Find(sFind, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1"
    End If
Next rng
```

Thus, you don't need another range object.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, one other thing - is it possible for sFind to be multiple values i.e "drek", "dorm","drab" etc?

Comment: Sure, you could use an array of strings for that, cf. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228137/how-can-i-use-a-for-each-loop-on-an-array](How can I use a for each loop on an array).